# Unable to connect using ssh on bitbucket

Tags: ruby-on-rails, git, ssh, bitbucket, rvm

**Problem**

I am getting the below error while **pushing** or **pulling** data from bitbucket.

```
git fetch --all
Fetching origin
Forbidden
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
```

I have the same ssh keys on my `~/.ssh/project_ssh_key` on bitbucket & my **mac**.

**What I have tried to fix it**

I tried to create a new ssh file and use the same using the below command.

```
eval "$(ssh-agent -s)"
ssh-add -K ~/.ssh/my_project_new_private_key
```

I have added the newly created key in bitbucket in ** Personal Settings --> ssh keys **
and pasted the public key but no luck.

I also tried `ssh -T git@bitbucket` & got the output as

```
logged in as chakreshwar

You can use git or hg to connect to Bitbucket. Shell access is disabled
```

**Earlier everything was working with the old key before I did the below**

```
1. I realized that my RoR application is not using **.ruby-version** & **.ruby-gemset**
2. I created a new gemset & use that gemset.
3. Move all the references from default to newly created gemset.
4. Bundle install and rails s to make sure everything works.

5. Delete all the old git branches from local which are no longer in use.
```

Comment: Can you run `git remote -v` and verify that the remote is actually pointing to where you want to pull code from?

Comment: yes, that is correct

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check first if you have a `~/.ssh/config` file.

Because if `ssh -T git@bitbucket` works, that means you have a `Host bitbucket` entry which references the right private key.

But in that case, git remote -v must reflects an SSH URL actually using that Host entry:

```
bitbucket:<me>/<myrepo>
```

(assuming your config file also have a `User git` line)

Not `bitbucket.org`, but `bitbucket`.

So:

```
cd /apth/to/local/repo
git remote set-url origin bitbucket:<me>/<myrepo>
```

Comment: Correct, If have an entry for host bitbucket, user = git, hostname = bitbuket.org. It is pointing to the newly created key

Comment: git remote -v gives, git@bitbucket.org:username/myrepo.git, What should I try now?

Comment: @ChakreshwarSharma You should change that remote URL to use the one specified by your SSH config file: see my edited answer. Then you can a git pull or fetch.

Comment: yes, it works, a little update in your answer in the last line, git remote set-url origin bitbucket:<me>/</myrepo>, you forgot to add origin

Comment: One thing more , I want to ask that if i removed the entries from config file and set the repo url like git@bitbucket.org:user/repo.git, it should also work

Comment: @ChakreshwarSharma No because it won't find the dedicate private key associated for that SSH access. Hence the `.ssh/config` file and the special SSH URL using the `Host` entry label (in your case "`bitbucket`").